# Form is not running after adding fields in it

Tags: python, django

Hie friends, I made a form using the class forms.py it was running smoothly, but next time when I added two new fields in that forms.py class then on executing the command "python manage.py syncdb " it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 52, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 75, in cursor
    cursor = self._cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 174, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
pysqlite2.dbapi2.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Answer (score 1):

Making changes to forms does not affect you database schema, there is no need to run syncdb after changing a form. 
The error you are receiving has its roots elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem is not with your forms.py but with your sqlite database file.can you delete the sqlite database file  and syncdb again

```
~$  rm default.db
~$ manage.py syncdb
```